# Uncaught SyntaxErrror: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in chrome

Tags: jquery, json, google-chrome, syntax-error, token

I'm having a problem within the jQuery `ajax` function. The following code works fine in Mozilla but doesn't work in IE or Chrome, when I try to identify the problem using Developer Tools in chrome I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL \n
$.ajax.success
```

and when I click on it it directs me to the `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` line.

```
function getdata(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc",
        data: "",
        success: function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            displayPlaylists(obj);
        }

    });
}
```

EDIT:
Ive found a solution that works in chrome but still not in IE

```
function getdata(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc",
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data) {
                    displayPlaylists(data);
                }

            });
    }
```

the addition of dataType:"json" means that the function expects json data to be returned and therefore parses it on arrival (it is equivalent to using jQuery.parseJSON), however as i said this solution still doesn't work in IE

Comment: Try connecting to : https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=json

Comment: With Chrome debugger, you can see the output as a JSON object as well. Under network, select the data resource that was retrieved, and you'll find a JSON tab. Can Chrome parse it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set dataType to json and browser will automatically parse json for you, see if it works for you

```
  function getdata(){
            $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType:'application/json',
                    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc",
                    data: "",
                    success: function(data) {                           
                        displayPlaylists(data);
                    }

                });
        }
```

Comment: This solution works in chrome without the contentType added, but still no results in IE

Answer (score 2):

Since jQuery already assumes it's JSON (from the HTTP header), `data` already *is* passed as JSON.

So what happens is that you're using `JSON.parse` on an object (the JSON).

This fais with the same reason:

```
JSON.parse({}); // parse an object
```

because the `{}` becomes a string:

```
[object Object]
```

which is not valid JSON at all.

So, just remove the `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

My javascript linter indicates that there's a unicode character in the JSON data which it chokes on. This shouldn't be the case as it's valid JSON but this bit:

```
"The Syndicate Challenge #4 World At War\r\nhttp://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003d49g7f5lkvQ8"
```

Seems to be the trouble causer. I'm not a 100% sure tho, as firefox seems to be able to parse the data anyway. The unicode character also seems out of place, but that could be me.

Comment: the json returned is validated by jsonlint

Comment: Is there a possibility of providing us with said json data?

Comment: Here's the json data btw: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc

Comment: I found an out of place unicode character, but I'm not sure whether that's causing the issue.

Comment: It's not a problem at all, remove the JSON.parse and instead pass data.data.items to your obj. Check my answer above for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Quite ironically, I have had that same problem in Chrome during the last week, but I suspect that it's not only with Chrome but with any browser.

Using Chrome Javascript Debugger, place a breakpoint on the like where you fill the var 'obj' and check if 'data' has more than one object contained inside the array. In case it does, you're probably trying to access the object that is inside the first index position of your data object.

If you sent an anonymous json object from the server to the page, access the first index, instead of data directly.

Like so:

```
function getdata(){
        $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheSyndicateProject/playlists?v=2&alt=jsonc",
                data: "",
                success: function(data) {
                    var obj = data.data.items;
                    displayPlaylists(obj);
                }

            });
    }
```

EDIT:

I debugged your link myself and after testing it further, I found that you don't even need to parse this object, really.
Look at my example above, pass data.data.items to your var obj and it will be loaded with all your objects from within the array.

See if that helps.

Comment: i dont think this will work because the data is returned as a string, however i found that if you add dataType:"json" then the data is parsed on arrival as a json object and therefore the data parameter can be used as an object like you have done above

Comment: @Jono Brogan, It does work, I tested it myself. I simply created a simple page only loading jquery file and that function, debugged it and data.data.items is effectively loaded with the items which are accessible like that.